# Tcl/Tk attach a single point of a canvas-line to another widget (or a tag)

Tags: tkinter, canvas, tcl, grouping

Consider I have a Tcl/Tk canvas with several simple shapes: ovals connected by 2-point lines. like this:

[image: connected shapes]

created like so:

```
canvas .c -width 400 -height 200
pack .c

proc create_shape {cnv tag x y} {
    $cnv create oval \
        [expr $x - 10] [expr $y - 10] \
        [expr $x + 10] [expr $y + 10] \
        -tags [list $tag shape]
    $cnv create text $x [expr $y - 15] -text ${tag} -tags [list $tag text]
    $cnv create rectangle $x $y $x $y -tags [list $tag center] -outline {}
}
proc connect {cnv src dst} {
    foreach {x0 y0} [$cnv coords "${src}&&center"] {break}
    foreach {x1 y1} [$cnv coords "${dst}&&center"] {break}
    $cnv create line $x0 $y0 $x1 $y1 -tags [list "src:$src" "dst:$dst" connection]
}

create_shape .c A 100 100
create_shape .c B 200 120
create_shape .c C 300 100

connect .c A B
connect .c B C
```

Now, I would like to be able to move my shapes around (e.g. `.c move B 0 20`) and have the connecting lines follow automatically.

I have come up with this:

```
proc move {cnv tag dx dy} {
    # move the object
    $cnv move  "${tag}&&!line" $dx $dy

    # adjust the connections
    foreach {x y} [$cnv coords "${tag}&&center"] {break}
    # find all connections coming from $cnv (and adjust their start-point)
    foreach id [$cnv find withtag "connection&&src:${tag}" ] {
        foreach {_ _ x1 y1} [$cnv coords $id] {$cnv coords $id $x $y $x1 $y1}
    }
    # find all connections going to $cnv (and adjust their end-point)
    foreach id [$cnv find withtag "connection&&dst:${tag}" ] {
        foreach {x0 y0 _ _} [$cnv coords $id] {$cnv coords $id $x0 $y0 $x $y}
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but I wonder whether there's a more elegant solution...

Also, it requires my own wrapper proc `move`.
Is it possible to achieve the same with some virtual event? E.g. so that I can issue `$cnv move $tag 10 20` or even `$cnv moveto $tag 123 456`, and the connections are "notified" and updated automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in mechanism for doing this. The canvas simply does not know the relationship of one item's control points to another's. (Changing that would require adding a solver to the coordinate handling system to do properly, which would be a lot of work so it is pretty unlikely to happen.)

But you could to is add in variable traces on something suitable so that when you update that variable with the logical coordinates of the entities you're really working with, the coordinates for the items displaying that entity are all updated automatically; the direction of information flow and application-specificity in that case makes it pretty straight forward to do. The variable(s) in question might be an array or member fields of an object.

Comment: interesting suggestion. (as of now, I don't really track the coordinates in a separate set of variables, as practically the entire state of the system is kept in an external process; i guess i'm trying to abuse as much of Tcl/Tk's internal state for my purposes and pretend that i'm stateless if i do this...)